# Convert .NET Core console application to self-contained application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET Core console application that I can run with the `dotnet` command locally.

Is it possibly we wrap this into a self-contained application for Windows 2012 Server without going back to Visual Studio or having the source code?  (i.e. with just the assemblies from the publish command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple console project **with the same name** and perform a self-contained publish. The tooling will resolve all necessary steps. You can then copy all files form the portable publish over the self-contained content. This will even work for .NET Core 2.0 where the name of the dll file to run is embedded into the main `.exe` file (for 1.0 / 1.1, it uses its own name to resolve the `.dll` file to run).

Alternatively you copy the shared framework to the destination directory and use its `corehost.exe yorapp.dll` to run your application.

Comment: Good idea, feels like a hack but I can't see why it wouldn't work.  Cheers.

Comment: Try it :). The reason for having a project is to get nuget to resolve the proper host that is compiled for the stand-alone mode. The muxer and dotnet/corehost aren't and might fail.

Comment: Muxer?  I haven't heard that term before.

Comment: (that's the main `dotnet.exe` in the root `\Program Files\dotnet` dir that shells out to whatever shared framework will be used)

Comment: OK, cheers.  I'll have a Google for "muxer", I assume it's a common term I just haven't come across before.